# How to setup the tax correctly? (we use the same tax percentage for everything)

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

It turns out the FedEx fees were being incorrectly calculated because the Shipping FROM settings were a ZIP code in California. I changed the shipping state and ZIP code to *Colorado* and a *specific ZIP in Colorado*. Now the tax is not being charged at all! I would guess it's because in the TAX Calculation Settings in Admin it says:

```
Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Origin
```

What is the best way to set up tax charging everyone the same tax percentage?

When I change the:

Tax Calculation Based On: to either of the options (Shipping Address, Billing Address, Shipping origin) - **it never charges tax anymore**.

I remember in the old Magento I just put in the percentage somewhere (like 8.5%) and that took care of things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do what I was trying to do - you should set things up in:

- SALES --) TAX --) Manage Tax Rates

and

- SALES --) TAX --) Manage Tax Rules

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html